# wordpress not opening after importing database

Tags: wordpress

well I have a little experience and read all the articles here about moving a site from one server to another

I uploaded the files and linked them to empty database and it works fine and ask me to install wordpress

but when I import the old database to the new empty one, the site doesn't open and keeps loading, all pages with wp-admin the same doesn't open

I think that mysql version has something to do with that, because the new server has an old version 5.1, and the old server where the database was exported from uses 5.5 version

any solution plz?

Comment: Did you actually migrate the database so that the entries in it match the new site's URL ?

Comment: yes, and I tried in the other times to find and replace urls via Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is one probability and other probability is issue in your `wp_options` table. Change `site_url` and `home` to match your configuration on the new server.

You may also need to change `wp-config.php` file to match configuration of your new server. If everything is alright, you should be able to logon to WP-Admin. Once you have logged in successfully, change Permalinks to some other structure and then revert back. This will create all URLs again in MySQL Database.

Comment: Helloyes, I did that exactly and I tried another thing which is replace old url with new by opening .sql with Notepad++ and imported the database again

Comment: here are some screenshots from tables and table wp_options which doesnt include Home field only, and siteurl which is correct

http://im65.gulfup.com/4xTgde.jpg
http://im65.gulfup.com/5eQ144.jpg

Answer (score -1):

It turned out to be the openbasedir function, I allowed it and that solved the issue.